# getting child categories base on parent category id using promises

Tags: reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

Understanding: my little understanding with promise is we can use it in place of callback functions.

Scenario: i will fetch parent categories from api than pass the categories array of objects to a function, a promise function may be ?

```
const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('API/categories?parent=0');
    const data = await res.json();
    return Promise.all(data.map(item => anAsyncFunction(item)))
}
```

this function recieves all the categories and i pass it to promise function

```
const anAsyncFunction = async item => {

    return functionWithPromise(item)
}
```

this returns right data all child categories in array of objects

```
const functionWithPromise = async data => { //a function that returns a promise
    const res = await fetch('API/categories?parent='+data.id);
    const datas = await res.json();
    // console.log(datas);
    
    // api call to insert all the records
    return Promise.resolve(data)
    
}
```

[image]

now i want to go through all these arrays and insert into database using api call

```
await api.create(postData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `anAsyncFunction` & `functionWithPromise` functions. Two functions are unnecessary.

The line `return Promise.resolve(data)` can be `return data`

`getData` is *thenable* which gives you array of promise responses. Loop thru it twice and use `Promise.all`

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("API/categories?parent=0");
  const data = await res.json();
  return Promise.all(data.map((item) => anAsyncFunction(item)));
};

const anAsyncFunction = async (data) => {
  const res = await fetch("API/categories?parent=" + data.id);
  const datas = await res.json();
  // api call to insert all the records
  //   return Promise.resolve(data);
  return datas;
};

getData().then((res) => {
  let promises = [];
  res.forEach((datas) => { //this loop is for each and every response
    datas.forEach((postData) => { //this loop is for
      promises.push(api.create(postData));
    });
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then((finalRes) => {
    console.log("finalRes", finalRes);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, i'm getting typeerror: res.json is not a function when i tried to implement this in react, i'm using strapi,

i hope it is returning all the child categories, how i can pass the parent id ? can i destructure it like below ?
          const { name, parentid } = postData;

Comment: got it working, checked the response and it was in data.data

Comment: awesome ... glad to hear... kindly consider to accept & upvote the answer.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can get parent id inside postData ? and can you please add some comments if possible how things are happening ?

Comment: added new object using map return datas.data.map(v => ({...v, parentCategory: data.id})), i'm not sure if it is correct way, couldn't find other way to get the parent id